# Find the PID(s) of running processes and store as an array

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I'm trying to write a bash script to find the PID of a running process then issue a kill command. I have it partially working, but the issue I face is that there may be more than one process running. I want to issue a kill command to each PID found.

I presume I need to put each PID in to an array but am at a loss as to how to do that.

What I have so far:

```
pid=$(ps -fe | grep '[p]rocess' | awk '{print $2}')
if [[ -n $pid ]]; then
    echo $pid
    #kill $pid
else
echo "Does not exist"
fi
```

What this will do is return all PIDs on a single line, but I can't figure out how to split this in to an array.

Comment: Check the `killall`  or `pkill`  command to save yourself a lot of work.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's a little one liner that might help

```
for pid in `ps -ef | grep your_search_term | awk '{print $2}'` ; do kill $pid ; done
```

Just replace **your_search_term** with the process name you want to kill.

You could also make it into a script and swap **your_search_term** for **$1**

**EDIT:** I suppose I should explain how this works.

The back ticks `` collects the output from the expression inside it.  In this case it will return a list of pids for a process name.

Using a for loop we can iterate through each pid and kill the process.

**EDIT2:** replaced kill -9 with kill

Comment: Don't `kill -9` unless you know processes are likely to fail closing neatly.

Comment: Also, `grep A | awk '{ B }'` is almost always better written `awk '/A/ { B }'`. If you want to pass in a regex as a parameter, `awk -v param=A '$0 ~ param { B }'`

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use an array if you're going to immediately iterate over the results and perform an action:

```
for pid in $(ps -fe | grep '[p]rocess' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'); do
    kill "$pid"
done
```

Notice we have to exclude `grep`'s pid from the list of processes to kill. Or we could just use `pgrep(1)`:

```
for pid in $(pgrep '[p]rocess'); do
    kill "$pid"
done
```

If you actually needed to store the pids in an array, `pgrep` is how you would do it:

```
pids=( $(pgrep '[p]rocess') )
```

Back to killing process. We can still do better. If we're just using `pgrep` to get a list of processes to kill them, why not go straight for `pgrep`'s sister program: `pkill(1)`?

```
pkill '[p]rocess'
```

As it turns out, no need for `bash` scripting at all.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know why you would ever grep for a process to kill, unless you didn't know the command name. Most modern versions of [ps](/questions/tagged/ps) have the flags

```
    -C cmdlist
          Select by command name.  This selects the processes whose executable name is given in cmdlist.
```

and

```
   -o format
          User-defined format.  format is a single argument in the form of
          a blank-separated or comma-separated list, which offers a way to
          specify individual output columns.  The recognized keywords are
          described in the STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS section below.
          Headers may be renamed (ps -o pid,ruser=RealUser -o
          comm=Command) as desired.  If all column headers are empty (ps
          -o pid= -o comm=) then the header line will not be output.
          Column width will increase as needed for wide headers; this may
          be used to widen up columns such as WCHAN (ps -o pid,wchan=WIDE-
          WCHAN-COLUMN -o comm).  Explicit width control (ps opid,
          wchan:42,cmd) is offered too.  The behavior of ps -o pid=X,
          comm=Y varies with personality; output may be one column named
          "X,comm=Y" or two columns named "X" and "Y".  Use multiple -o
          options when in doubt.  Use the PS_FORMAT environment variable
          to specify a default as desired; DefSysV and DefBSD are macros
          that may be used to choose the default UNIX or BSD columns.
```

So you can just do

```
ps -o pid= -C commandName
```

Will return the pid of all processes named exactly commandName and is cleaner and faster. Or kill a loop

```
while read -r pid; do 
  kill "$pid" 
done < <(ps -o pid= -C commandName)
```

But really, you should always just be able to do

```
> pkill commandName
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script seems fine, if you want to have each pid list on a new like then replace:

```
echo $pid
#kill $pid
```

with

```
echo "$pid"
#kill "$pid"
```

Comment: This is poor advice. Without the quotes, the shell splits the variable's value into tokens on whitespace, so when the variable contains multiple PIDs, `kill` receives them as positional arguments. *With* the quotes, the variable is passed to `kill` as a single parameter, with newlines and all, which is not a valid argument to `kill`. So the quotes only work sort of by accident only when the variable contains a single PID, and provide no value (or actually, only negative value).